# Find first occurrence in a row in data frame

Tags: pandas

I have small dataset defined as follows;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'id':['id1', 'id2', 'id3'],
 'cmp1':[1,0,0],
 'cmp2':[0,1,0],
  'cmp3':[1,0,0]})
```

The goal is to add a new column called `col` which'll tell the first occurrence of 1 for every row among the columns, `cmp1`,`cmp2`,`cmp3`. Hence the final output shd look like;

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
'id':['id1', 'id2', 'id3'],
 'cmp1':[1,0,0],
 'cmp2':[0,1,0],
  'cmp3':[1,0,0],
  'col':['first', 'second','none']})
```

As you can see for `id=id1`, 1 occurred for the very first time in cmp1, hence we have first in `col`.It is irrespective of the fact that we have `cmp2=0`, and again `cmp3=1`.
Can I get some help on how to define this new column, `col`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.max(axis=1)` to find those rows with at least one `1`, then `np.where` with `idxmax` (for the column name):

```
# the actual data columns
data = df.iloc[:, 1:]

df['col'] = np.where(data.max(axis=1), data.idxmax(axis=1), 'none')
```

Output:

```
    id  cmp1  cmp2  cmp3   col
0  id1     1     0     1  cmp1
1  id2     0     1     0  cmp2
2  id3     0     0     0  none
```

If you insist on `first`, `second`,... you would need to do manually

```
labels = np.array(['first', 'second', 'third'])
df['col'] = np.where(data.max(axis=1), labels[data.to_numpy().argmax(axis=1)], 'none')
```

and output:

```
    id  cmp1  cmp2  cmp3     col
0  id1     1     0     1   first
1  id2     0     1     0  second
2  id3     0     0     0    none
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `idxmax()` with `axis=1`

```
cmp = df.filter(like='cmp')
df.loc[cmp.eq(1).any(axis=1), 'col'] = cmp.eq(1).idxmax(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    id  cmp1  cmp2  cmp3   col
0  id1     1     0     1  cmp1
1  id2     0     1     0  cmp2
2  id3     0     0     0   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of idxmax() and a mask to find the answer

```
df['first'] = df.drop(['id'], axis = 1).mask(df.eq(0)).idxmax(axis = 1).fillna('None')
```